# Are messages sent with transactions in Trinity public?

Tags: transaction, address

Can anyone see what the message was that I sent today to PEUTKRIYWYRJFLEPZWHKEDLSXZEDOFJKBDODKVTDKMP9C9UGGNVXWYJEWNYDWHVCUVGQHRFJPTRKANMBCYLTLUTEOY along with 1 Gi? If yes, how?

Comment: Peuter sends money across the globe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the message part is just an unencrypted message that everyone can read; It is encoded with the asciiToTrytes method which can be detected and decoded on the fly. You can see this here:

https://thetangle.org/transaction/EB9ONODEXADXDUNJXYQEGEKYQXRGKQWQKLYSUYFGKUBCTNVMNDMWNFVXFBEFDQCHLGWNEKVETYFRA9999